# Change visualforce pages font in managed package

Tags: visualforce, managed-package, lightning, font

I have a managed package and to be Lightning Ready, I'm wondering if changing the font to `Salesforce Sans` is a good idea ?

And if so, how can I change the font for all my pages in my application (without changing font of native Salesforce pages)?